# Google Analytics Mobile Android just not displaying all the data

Tags: android, google-analytics

After watching the video from IO [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-B9mNAmzTI), I managed to install the API as well as the EasyTracker. I had just two activities, and ActivityTwo is created by another. I @Override two of my onStart() activities and inserted in both (with different text of course):

```
EasyTracker.getTracker().trackPageView("/ActivityOne");
```

I also added a few events like this in a few places:

```
EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent("Operation", "Back to start", null, 0);
```

I received real time data, but for only one activity/page, and not the other. None of the events came through. What exactly am I doing wrong here?